# Prevent page scroll to the top when popup display in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, popup, angular8, kendo-ui-window

I have a button in the bottom of the page , once the button click, a popup display. However, the page automatically scroll all the way to the top, so I have to scroll down manually to be able to see the popup. I even added a function to scroll down to current position, but it's still no working. I would like both the screen and the popup stay at the bottom.

html file

```
   <button (click)=" goToBottom(); openPopup('Image',300)">CLICK FOR IMAGE</button>
```

typescript file

```
goToBottom(){
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }

 openPopup(winTitle, winWidth) {
      const windowRef = this.window_S.open({
        appendTo: this.ngWinRef,
        title: winTitle,
        content: AComponent,
        width: winWidth,
        top: window.innerHeight / 3+ window.scrollY,
        left: (window.innerWidth - winWidth) / 4
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: looks like `top: window.innerHeight / 3+ window.scrollY,` line is a culprit.

Comment: @kshitij When I commented out top:window.innerHeight / 3+ window.scrollY, both popup and screen are all scroll to the top, if add that line, the popup are stay at the place it should be, but the screen are scroll all the way to the top. I would to have both of them stay at the bottom.